# Determining XY location of text within multi-line text components

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, cursor, jeditorpane

I have a multi-line paragraph displayed in a JEditorPane with certain words within them hyperlinked. I have custom HyperlinkListeners attached to these links that, among other things, returns the location of the cursor on the screen when they are clicked.

I want to get this information when the JEditorPanes are initialized, before the links are clicked. How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can find the words in the model then you can use:

```
Point p = editorPane.modelToView( ... );
```

Comment: like a charm. Muchos gracias.